# ubuntu failed to boot and just stuck

Tags: boot, 18.04

[image: Stuck image]

When I'm try to open ubuntu,it stuck and doesn't want to open
I tried to open in recovery mode and make some commands like
Sudo apt-get update
But failed because the network is disabled and I am try to enable network but it's also failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **a:** 18.04 is 'end of life' so not supported, updates are likely to fail solely because of this (unless you have `Extended Security Maintenance`, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).
- **b:** for a fully enabled recovery mode; select options for `fsck`  (to make disks writable [look for failure]) then `enable networking` and finally
  `drop to root shell` (hit Enter once to see the bash prompt).
- **c:** in recovery mode; look into `dmesg | less` to begin with, if no traces to the failure there, then there might be in other
  files in `/var/log/`.